# Chinese remainder theorem and Wikipedia Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm looking at the proof

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(direct_construction)

for the existence in the Chinese remainder theorem.

> Isn't the proof that $\;0\le x\le N$ missing? How do I prove it starting from 
>   $$
> x=\sum _{i=1}^{k}a_{i}M_{i}N_{i}?
> $$

See the link for the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is a solution of the system of congruences, but it doesn't have to be smaller than $N$ indeed. After having computed it, you simply replace it by its remainder after dividing it by $N$.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the point. But IMO the proof has to contain a comment about it, otherwise the $x$ in the claim is not necessarily the $x$ in the proof.

Comment: Yes, you are right.